# Let $\{x_n\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the following statements are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{x_n\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\displaystyle \lim _{k\to\infty} \|x_k\|= \infty$
> 2. $\{x_n\}$ has no convergent subsequences.
> 3. For each bounded set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the index set $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_k \in X$ is finite.

What I've done so far:

(1 $\Rightarrow$ 2) $\forall$ $M>0 \in \mathbb{R^n}$, $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq n_0$ $\Rightarrow ||x_n|| > M$. And this implies that {$x_n$} is not bounded (Right?). Let {$x_{n_k}$} be a subsequence of {$x_n$}. We have that {$x_{n_k}$} is not bounded, so it does not converges.

(2 $\Rightarrow$ 3) Since {$x_n$} has no convergent subsequences, it does not converges. I'm stuck here.

Any hints, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that for some cube $Q$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ containing $x_{k}$ infinitely many. Divide the cube into congruent $2^{n}$ cubes and look for one that contains infinitely many $x_{k}$, and proceed this fashion, you get a limit point, and a subsequence that converges to this point.

$3\rightarrow 1$ is easy. For any $M>0$, consider the bounded set $\{|x|\leq M\}$, then choose the maximal $N$ such that $x_{N}\in\{|x|\leq M\}$, then for all $n\geq N+1$, we have $|x_{n}|>M$.